# How to get window origin (position) in mate applet?

Tags: python, gtk, mate

I try to get window origin in a mate panel applet.
To be more precise I want to know the position of my applet (x and y) on the screen because I have a button which show/hide a `Gtk.window` but I need to move that window next to my button (above, below, right, left depending on where the mate panel is)

[image]

The only way that I found is to call `get_origin` but there is a problem. It should return a tuple x,y but instead like the c function it require two integers and since python use pass by value of course it doesn't work.

This code is valid but useless:

```
window = self.get_window()
x = 0
y = 0
window.get_origin(x, y)
```

All other "way to use" `get_origin` (that you can found in any doc) does not work because it require 3 args (I don't know why)

So I'm looking for a way to get the position of my applet (even if it's not accurate) or to move my window next to my button.

Comment: Is this pygtk or python-gobject (`from gi import`)?

Comment: @andlabs it's I guess python-gobject `from gi.repository import Gtk` and Gtk 2.0 not Gtk3

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Using `get_origin()` should work. Are you calling it after the window was mapped?

Comment: @elya5 if I can do `x,y = window.get_origin()` I guess, but it's not the case and it return always 1. All other functions that I tried work as expected, so I need something else which do the same thing. I call it when I click on my button so yes the window is mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative [get_root_coords](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gdk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gdk.Window.get_root_coords)

```
window = self.get_window()
x,y = window.get_root_coords(0, 0)
```

It works even with multiple screens and I'm able to move my `Gtk.Window` next to my button with it.